# How do I get rid of space between images on slider?

Tags: html, css, slider, image-gallery

Hello I am trying to create a clean/simple image slider with just HTML/CSS. I've managed to create one however have very large spaces between each slide and have tried a few things to get rid of them.

[Screenshot of space between images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KggS.jpg)

HTML CODE

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide-1"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-2"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-3"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-4"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-5"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
</div><div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide-1"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-2"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-3"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-4"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-5"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px ;
  margin: 0px ;
}

.slider {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 650px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 0px ;
  padding: 0px ;
}
```

- I've tried setting the margin/padding to 0 for slide/slider/image class (rio-womens)
- I found a similar question on here which said to add in this CSS code:

```
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Which sadly did not work, as it made my images disappear. So I got rid of 'display: none'. Which made my images return however left me with the same problem as before (spaces between images).

I've tried using a few different carousel codes, including bootstrap/jss slider. However as my images are different sizes/horizontal and portrait I found they weren't quite right. This has been the closest to what I'm looking for so far - clean and simple and slide from left to right.

Would appreciate any help on this as I've been trying to figure this out for days now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `width: 100%` from `.slide`

```css
.slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px ;
  margin: 0px ;
}

.slider {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 650px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 0px ;
  padding: 0px ;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide-1"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-2"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-3"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-4"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-5"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
</div><div class="slider">
  <div class="slide" id="slide-1"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-2"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-3"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-4"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" width="100%" alt="♥"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-5"><img class="rio-womens" src="https://i.imgur.com/8E2Z8s5.jpg" height="100%" alt="♥"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was such a simple thing. Thank you so much, really appreciate it.

Comment: @shannonkelseyann No problem. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

maybe inside your class "slide" with :

justify-content : "space-between" or "space-around" or "space-evenly" ?

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove width="100%" and height="100% from your HTML CODE.